# tcp port numbers reused on wireshark

Tags: tcp, wireshark, network-protocols

I used raw socket to build a tcp client program on machine A to reproduce tcp 3-way handshake with a simple regular tcp server on machine B

I captured packets on the client host and  server host, and got the captured file as below

client:
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B09y_TWqTtwlZ1NleS1NNmR4Sk0/edit?usp=sharing

server:
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B09y_TWqTtwlc3lZUmNyV1R4X0k/edit?usp=sharing

there are 3 packets, SYN, SYN/ACK, AKC on the client side, the wireshark interace shows that this is a normal tcp 3-way handshake, but on the server side, it shows : tcp port numbers reused, what is wrong with this?

but when I use

netstat -tnp

I see the tcp connection has been established
what is wrong with this? thanks!

Comment: Your wireshark log is incomplete: On the server side, you should see the syn packet coming in from 201.109. I suspect I know what the problem is, but having more of the log would really be helpful.

Comment: The *full* wireshark log. Did you have any filters on when you saved the logs? You should turn them off if so.

Comment: they are the full wireshark log, the server machine is a PlanetLab node. so what do you guess are the potential reasons?

Comment: besides, I see from netstat -tnp that the tcp connection is established, so I use raw socket to create some data packets, with the correct sequence number, ack_seq number , source port and destination port, but the server side doesn't receive the packet, why?

Comment: So, you're saying that these two computers have *no other* network traffic on these interfaces?

Comment: on the server machine, I can only capture these 3 packets without using any filters. on the client machine there are some NFS data which are not due to my program